# How to get all category is active in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, phtml, category-listing

i tryed get all category in phtml by this code, but it not working, it get all category, not only category active. Please help me. Thanks all.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->setStore($storeManager->getStore());
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to put below code into your block file.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

   class Categoryinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {    
       protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
           array $data = []
       )
       {
            $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }


       public function getActiveCategoryCollection()
       {
           $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
           $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');        
           $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
           return $collection;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Now into your phtml file you can call those function like this :

   ```
   $categories = $block->getActiveCategoryCollection();
   foerach($categories as $category)
   {
       // DO YOUR LOGIC
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Create your block and put below code in block php file

```
<?php
namespace Module\Example\Block;

class Categorydata extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
public function getCategories()
{
$categoryFactory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
return $categories;
}
}
?>
```

after that paste below code into view phtml file.

```
<?php 
    $collection = $block->getCategories();
    foreach ($collection as $categorycollection){
        $categorycollection->getName();
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you try Following way..

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// get the list of all categories
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryCollection->create();
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->getIsActive()){
        echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
        echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
        echo $category->getUrl() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need active or inactive both categories so used this code.

```
        <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setStore($storeManager->getStore());
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "Category Id - ".$cat->getId();
            echo "Category Name - ".$cat->getName();     
        }

        ?>
```